# Accordeon Menu should stay open on subpage

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, menu

I created a simple accordeon menu with the following jquery java script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#nav > li > a').click(function(){
    if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active'){
      $('#nav li ul').slideUp();
      $(this).next().slideToggle();
      $('#nav li a').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
    }
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8y60hre0/

The problem is that it closes all submenus when I'm on a subpage.

How can I change the code, that the specific subpage menu stays open when I'm on its subpages?

When I'm active on a subpage there will be an "active" class added to the li tag.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: use `id` on `li` and on each page set it with `$("#subMenuA").click();` in DOM.

Comment: Check https://jsfiddle.net/8y60hre0/6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `slideToggle()` submenus every time page loads. In this example it's simulates user click on `active`s parent link or on `active` link if it's not in submenu.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#nav > li > a').click(function(){
    if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active'){
      $('#nav li ul').slideUp();
      $(this).next().slideToggle();
      $('#nav li a').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
    }
  });
  if($(".active").parent().parent().is('#nav')){
    $(".active").next().slideToggle();
  }else{
   $(".active").parents('ul').siblings('a').click();
  }
 
});
```

```css
#nav {
    float: left;
    width: 280px;
}
#nav li a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    list-style:none;
}
#nav li a:hover, #nav li a.active {
}
#nav li ul {
    display: none; // used to hide sub-menus
     list-style:none;
}
#nav li ul li a {
    padding: 10px 25px;
}
ul{
  list-style:none;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="nav">
  <li><a href="#" >Item 1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" class="active">Sub-Item 1 a</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 1 b</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 1 c</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 2</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 2 a</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 2 b</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 3</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 3 a</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 3 b</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 3 c</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 3 d</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 4</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 4 a</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 4 b</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 4 c</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here's a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8y60hre0/8/) with possible solution

Comment: Thank you very much, now its woking and just an other question appeared. How is it possible to avoid the slide effect - it should simply appeare and disappeare...I was triying with other code like "show" or "hide" to replace "slide" but it didn't work.

Comment: Oh i just found out. I have to replace .slideToggle(); with .toggle();

First I failed with the uppercase T

Simple as this :D